# Slug field creation using ID

Tags: django, django-models

this the postmodel and trying to create a slug unique field
The Slug field creation error str(self.id) is returning "none" where as the seld.title is working correctly

```
class postmodel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    subject=models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_post_dpetail', (),
                {
                    'slug': self.slug,
                })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:

            self.slug = slugify(self.title)+"-"+str(self.id)
        super(postmodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get `self.id` until the object is **saved** in your database. So you can modify your `save()` method to:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(postmodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Save your model in order to get the id

    # Then implement the logic for the slug

    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + str(self.id)
        self.save()  # Call save() again in order to save the slug
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.id` is auto increment field in the database, it is exist only after you save object in the database, so you have created a stalemate:

You can save object if `slug` is none and you can create slug while you not save the object.

hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

so I came up with a good enough solution based on previous answers.

## In models.py

this allows slugfield to be blank when you first submit the form...

```
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, allow_unicode=True, blank=True)
```

override the save function to 1. create the post 2. set the slug of the instance of the post to title + id of the post.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + str(self.id)
    return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it helps.